# spread same value into multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, spread

this is my starting df

```
test <- data.frame(ident = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                   cult1 = c("CER", "CER", "CER", "INF", "INF"), 
                   cult2 = c("GEX", "GEX", "GEX", "GEX", "GEX"), 
                   cult3 = c(NA, "ORG", "ORG", NA, NA), 
                   prod = c(11050,2134,0,26250,2124),
                   value = c(19785,34132,9207,6987,4455),
                   weight = c(0,0,56,13,556))
```

I try to spread value, prod and weight for each cult, if its not NA, so far i ve done it but with NA named columns, also i need to duplicate columns value, prod weight for each spread as it get deleted afterwhile.

```
        test <- test %>% mutate (prod2 = prod,
                                 prod3 = prod,
                                 value2 = value,
                                 value3 = value,
                                 weight2 = weight,
                                 weight3 = weight)
        
        
        test <- test %>% mutate(CATEGORIE_TEMP = paste0("P_", cult1)) %>%
          spread(key = CATEGORIE_TEMP, value = "prod")
        
        test <- test %>% mutate(CATEGORIE_TEMP = paste0("V_", cult1)) %>%
          spread(key = CATEGORIE_TEMP, value = "value")
        
        test <- test %>% mutate(CATEGORIE_TEMP = paste0("W_", cult1)) %>%
          spread(key = CATEGORIE_TEMP, value = "weight")
        
        test <- test %>% mutate(CATEGORIE_TEMP = paste0("P_", cult2)) %>%
          spread(key = CATEGORIE_TEMP, value = "prod2")
          
          test <- test %>% mutate(CATEGORIE_TEMP = paste0("V_", cult2)) %>%
          spread(key = CATEGORIE_TEMP, value = "value2")
        
        test <- test %>% mutate(CATEGORIE_TEMP = paste0("W_", cult2)) %>%
          spread(key = CATEGORIE_TEMP, value = "weight2")
    
        test <- test %>% mutate(CATEGORIE_TEMP = paste0("P_", cult3)) %>%
          spread(key = CATEGORIE_TEMP, value = "prod3")
      
         test <- test %>% mutate(CATEGORIE_TEMP = paste0("V_", cult3)) %>%
          spread(key = CATEGORIE_TEMP, value = "value3")
    
         test <- test %>% mutate(CATEGORIE_TEMP = paste0("W_", cult3)) %>%
          spread(key = CATEGORIE_TEMP, value = "weight3")

#removing the NA named columns
test <- test %>% select(-ends_with("NA"))
```

It s there a more efficient way to do this ?
I do not have pivot_wider function as i am running an old R version.

Expected result :

```
  ident cult1 cult2 cult3 P_CER P_INF V_CER V_INF W_CER W_INF P_GEX V_GEX W_GEX P_ORG V_ORG W_ORG
1     1   CER   GEX  <NA> 11050    NA 19785    NA     0    NA 11050 19785     0    NA    NA    NA
2     2   CER   GEX   ORG  2134    NA 34132    NA     0    NA  2134 34132     0  2134 34132     0
3     3   CER   GEX   ORG     0    NA  9207    NA    56    NA     0  9207    56     0  9207    56
4     4   INF   GEX  <NA>    NA 26250    NA  6987    NA    13 26250  6987    13    NA    NA    NA
5     5   INF   GEX  <NA>    NA  2124    NA  4455    NA   556  2124  4455   556    NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can call it more efficient, but at least it is one code block:

```
test2 <- test %>% 
  gather(cult1:cult3, key = "key", value = "cult") %>% 
  mutate(prod_cult = paste0("P_",cult),
         value_cult = paste0("V_",cult),
         weight_cult = paste0("W_",cult)) %>% 
  spread(key = key, value = cult) %>% 
  spread(key = prod_cult, value = prod) %>% 
  spread(key = value_cult, value = value) %>%
  spread(key = weight_cult, value = weight) %>%
  group_by(ident) %>% 
  summarise_all(~first(na.omit(.))) %>%
  select(-ends_with("NA"))
```

Comment: Thx, I think it s more efficient.

Comment: also i add , na.rm = T in the gather so I don't need to erase th "NA" columns created